# How to shift X and Y positions so that 0,0 is in the middle of Element

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

```
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
```

Is there a way to make this go to the middle insead of the top left corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the translate method.

```
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the coordinate system with [`ctx.translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate). In this case you want to move it half the width rightwards and half the height downwards.

```
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
```

If you only want this translation to be temporary, have a look at the [`ctx.save()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [`ctx.restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) methods.